# What does 'b' mean in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

In the following query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT pass 
                 FROM table_name 
                 WHERE ssid=?) b 
  WHERE pass=?
```

what does `ssid) b WHERE pass=?;` actually mean in the original query?

Comment: It's just naming/identifying your select statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT pass FROM table_name WHERE ssid=?) b WHERE pass=?
```

same as:

```
SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT pass FROM table_name WHERE ssid=?) AS b WHERE pass=?
```

`b` is alias name for subquery. Then in your outer query you can refer to columns like:

```
SELECT b.pass FROM (SELECT pass FROM table_name WHERE ssid=?) AS b
```

See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)

> Subqueries are legal in a SELECT statement's FROM clause. The actual
> syntax is:
>
> SELECT ... FROM (subquery) [AS] name ...
>
> **The [AS] name clause is mandatory, because every table in a FROM
> clause must have a name**. Any columns in the subquery select list must
> have unique names.

Comment: +1; could you please explain how does that influence the result? can you give a full example with a dumpy table :-)

Comment: One of the many reasons I am not fond of the common practice of omitting the `AS`.

Comment: @AK_ it does not influence the result in any manner. MySQL requires subqueries to have aliases; in this instance it serves no other purpose than to satisfy that requirement. In other cases, such as JOINing the subquery to a table (or another subquery) it provides a name to use when referencing it's result fields (which is needed in cases of ambiguity where the subquery result field shares a name with a field of whatever it is being combined with).

Answer (score 0):

It's simply being used as an identifier for the nested selection statement. It's effectively assigning the results of that query to an imaginary table named 'b', so you can treat that nested statement much like you would a normal table.